# Is difference between two pointers legal c++17 constant expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constant-expression

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) section **Core constant expressions** point *19)* a subtraction operator between two pointers is not legal constant expression **until c++14**. Can I assume that following code is legal c++17 code or is this interpretation an abuse?

```
int X, Y;

template <long long V>
struct S { };

int main() {
    S<&X - &Y> s;
    (void)s;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question is moot. Pointer arithmetics is only defined on the pointers belonging to the same array, which is certainly not the case there. So, the code above is **not** legal C++, and in fact, fails to compile with compilers available to me.

Comment: Or two null pointers IIRC, which is also certainly not the case.

Comment: So I over-interpreted the wording? Yep I tested it too but I learnt that the fact something isn't compiling in given compiler doesn't really meen it actually is not legal hence the question :)

Comment: @hvd, i do not remember any exception for null pointers regarding the subtraction, but my memory may fail me. Would you be so kind to provide a quote?

Comment: @W.F., while compilers, may, indeed, have bugs, when several compilers agree on something, it's a strong hint that you are the one which got it wrong :-P

Comment: @SergeyA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128168/is-the-behavior-of-subtracting-two-null-pointers-defined is easier to find for me than the quote in the standard :)

Comment: @SergeyA I agree, however this is c++17 theoretically not yet supported fully by the compilers ;) :-P

Comment: @SergeyA Thank you for the response! I'll give a little bit more time to possible other suggestions and if nothing shows up I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @W.F. this was post-c++14 DR [1313](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1313) (now noted at the bottom of that cppreference page)

Answer (score 3):

The quoted cppref [article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) says

> A core constant expression is any expression that does not have any
>   one of the following ..
>
> 7) An expression whose evaluation leads to any form of core language
>   (since C++17) undefined behavior (including signed integer overflow,
>   division by zero, **pointer arithmetic outside array bound**s, etc).
>   Whether standard library undefined behavior is detected is
>   unspecified. (since C++17)
>
> 19) a subtraction operator between two pointers(until C++14)

Likely only array ptr arithemtics inside array bounds is getting 'legalized' since c++14, not all pointer arithmetics

---

Actually a [demo](https://godbolt.org/g/pmdYlV) shows that array ptr arithmetics compiles alright even with c++11 (not c++98)